# Copying a file automatically with a pom

Tags: maven, intellij-idea, kotlin

I have 3 modules in my Intellij project:

- a Java module
- a Kotlin module
- a misc files module

I have an XSD file in the misc files module that I need to have an exact copy of in the Kotlin module's test resources folder. i.e. whenever I update it, I need to copy it to the Kotlin module.

How can I update my Kotlin module's maven POM file so that it can automatically copy this file?

Comment: What is this file for? Is it a project resource? When is it going to be used? Where should it end up in the final product?

Comment: yes a resource file. You know, I don't know about the final product yet - I'm just talking about the test resource folder of the kotlin module (as a destination for the copy) - it is used for some reporting that is done from running a special test (might sound strange but tests were a good way to do this reporting since they can be parameterized, which was useful for this project)

Comment: Then it sounds like the Kotlin module has a dependency on the misc module. Add a `<dependency>` with that regard, and place the files under the Misc project `src/main/resources` folder. This way, the Kotlin module will access it like any classpath resource.

Comment: ok, I'll look into that - I'm new to inter-module operations - thanks

Comment: oh well, that isn't going to work. After investigating what the `.xsd` file is actually used for (this is an old project I haven't touched in a while), it is referenced by XML files in the Kotlin module as their schema. So, the file needs to be physically in the resources folder of the Kotlin module. Of course it is also referenced by XML files in the misc files module, which is why I need the same XSD file in both modules. So I guess my original question still stands...

Comment: will it work to extract those files into an own module into src/main/resources and depend on it from the others using scope test? so you can avoid creating additional test-jars.

Answer (score 0):

You can't copy files with `Maven` directly, but there is a plugin for it to execute `Ant` tasks. One of the pre-defined tasks is `copy` and can be used as seen below. It can hook into the various phases of `Maven` execution. This may require some fiddling.

```
<build>
  <plugins>
    <plugin>
      <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
      <artifactId>maven-antrun-plugin</artifactId>
      <version>1.8</version>
      <executions>
        <execution>
          <id>copy-war-to-docker</id>
          <phase>package</phase>
          <goals>
            <goal>run</goal>
          </goals>
          <configuration>
            <target>
              <copy file="${build.warFile}"
                    tofile="${basedir}/docker/${build.name}.war"/>
            </target>
          </configuration>
        </execution>
      </executions>
    </plugin>
  </plugins>
</build>
```